# Java- Addition of two valus of a 2d Array

Tags: java

I do a matrix and I want to change the values of the original value, by adding the value of the position where you are and the value of the right sight of it. For example the new value of the position [0][0] should be [0][0](original value)+[0][1]. And when there is no value it should be just added 0. But when I do this I get this error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. So does anybody know how to fix this problem? That's my code:

```
public class Matrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] matrix = { { 1, 8, 1 }, { 4, 2, 4 }, { 1, 8, 1 } };
        print(matrix);

        System.out.println("\n");
        int[][] blur = blurMatrix(matrix);
        print(blur);
    }

    public static int[][] blurMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        if (matrix == null)
            return null;
        if (matrix.length <= 0)
            return null;

        int[][] blur = new int[matrix.length][];

        for (int row = 0; row < blur.length; row++) {
            blur[row] = new int[matrix[row].length];

            for (int col = 0; col < blur[row].length; col++) {
                blur[row][col] = (matrix[row][col] + matrix[row][col + col]);
                if (blur[row] == null)
                    return null;
                // if(blur[col]==null)return null;
            }
        }
        return blur;
    }

    public static void print(int[][] m) {
        if (m == null) {
            System.out.print(" no matrix to print!");
            return;
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < m.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < m[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(m[row][col] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `blur[row][col] = (matrix[row][col] + matrix[row][col + col]);` the problem is `col + col` since you can only access a max of `blur[row].length` and col is max `blur[row].length-1`. only you call `col + col` if `col>blur[row].length/2` it accesses a value bigger than the max and therefore the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do **matrix[row][col + col]**, you are trying to read out of the matrix. Also it should be **matrix[row][col + 1]**.
You need to do the blur on all columns except the last one which should remain unchanged.

This should fix your problem:

```
  public static int[][] blurMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    if(matrix == null || matrix.length <= 0)
      return null;

    int[][] blur = new int[matrix.length][];

    for(int row =0; row < blur.length; row++) {
      blur[row]= new int[matrix[row].length];

      // for all cols except the last one (we do not modify the last row)
      for(int col=0; col<blur[row].length-1; col++) {
        int cellValue = matrix[row][col];
        int nextCellValue = matrix[row][col+1];
        blur[row][col] = cellValue + nextCellValue;
      }

      // for the last column
      int lastColumnIndex = blur[row].length-1;
      blur[row][lastColumnIndex]= matrix[row][lastColumnIndex];
    }
    return blur;
  }
```

**EDIT:** To do it in the other direction

```
  public static int[][] blurMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    if(matrix == null || matrix.length <= 0)
      return null;

    int[][] blur = new int[matrix.length][];

    for(int row =0; row < blur.length; row++) {
      blur[row]= new int[matrix[row].length];

      // for all cols except the first one (we do not modify the first row)
      for(int col=blur[row].length-1; col>0; col--) {
        int cellValue = matrix[row][col];
        int previousCellValue = matrix[row][col-1];
        blur[row][col] = cellValue + previousCellValue;
      }

      // for the first column
      blur[row][0] = matrix[row][0];
    }
    return blur;
  }
```

**EDIT** Applying the 2 blur methods to the original matrix

I think what you are doing is applying the 2 blur methods sequentially

```
int[][] blur = blurMatrix1(matrix);
print(blur);
System.out.println("");
blur = blurMatrix2(blur);
print(blur);
```

which results in 
after first pass
9  9  1
6  6  4
9  9  1

after second pass
9  18  10
6  12  10
9  18  10

What you seem to want to do is apply the 2 methods on the original one and then sum them

```
int[][] blur1 = blurMatrix1(matrix);
print(blur1);
System.out.println("");
int[][] blur2 = blurMatrix2(matrix);
print(blur2);
System.out.println("");
```

which result in 
first blur
9  9  1
6  6  4
9  9  1

second blur
1  9  9
4  6  6
1  9  9

now if you add them you get
10 18 10
10 12 10
10 18 10

Comment: Do you maybe know how it works in the opposite direction, I thought it is just the  opposite matrix[row][col-1]?

Comment: yes but the loop should be for(int col=blur[row].length-1; col>0; col--) and for the first column, you have blur[row][0] = matrix[row][0];

Comment: Ok I did this know to add the previous value but now I get again an exception

Comment: for(int col=blur[row].length-1; col>0; col--) {
    int cellValue = blur[row][col];
    int lastColValue = matrix[row][col-1];
    blur[row][col]=cellValue+lastColValue;
   }

Comment: I edited the answer with the code for the other direction.

Comment: Ok thx but when you combine both directions the value of the first col are now not the same as the last what they should be.

Comment: Ok but the values aren't correct I want them (1st col)9,6,9 then(2nd col) 10,10,10 and (3rd col)9,6,9

Comment: Then your algorithm is not correct. You should make an other question. This question here was about the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.